# Conectar banco de dados SQL Server no Django

Tags: sql, python, sql-server, django

Tenho um banco de dados SQL Server que já existe, e preciso conecta-lo ao meu projeto em Django.

Venho aqui então para ver se alguém já encontrou uma solução para o problema, pois ainda não conseguir resolver o mesmo depois de várias horas de pesquisa. obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Primeira coisa a fazer é instalar o pacote com [backend Django para Azure e SQL Server](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/):

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure
```

Depois no arquivo de configurações do Django(settings.py) procure o dicionário `DATABASES` e faça a seguinte alteração provendo os valores adequados a sua aplicação para NAME, USER, PASSWORD, HOST e PORT:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Nome do seu banco de dados',
        'USER': 'Nome do usuário',
        'PASSWORD': 'Senha',
        'HOST': 'Nome da instancia do SQL Server a ser utilizada',
        'PORT': 'Número da porta de comunicação',
    },
}
```

Dai só testar a comunicação com o banco de dados.

Comment: Deu certo! muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @murilokrugner vale a pena marcara a resposta como aceita ([veja o pq](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta))

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de recomendar a biblioteca **django-mssql-backend**, para a documentação oficial segue o link:. https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/

É a solução que eu atualmente adoto para os meus projetos pessoais e profissionais, nunca tive problemas com seu uso, a instalação se dá pelo seguinte código:

```
pip install django-mssql-backend
```

OBS:. lembre-se de ler atentamente a documentação, isso é importante!

Exemplo( settings.py ):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}

# set this to False if you want to turn off pyodbc's connection pooling
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```

Uma das dependências é o pyodbc na versão 3.0 ou maior, a lib oferece também suporte a regex, o que eu utilizo com frequência.

Caso você tenha problemas com essa lib, fique atento se o mesmo não ocorre pela necessidade da instalação de um "ODBC DRIVER", isso é mais propenso a ocorrer em sistemas operacionais linux.

Para maiores detalhamentos basta somente ler a documentação oficial,

Boa Sorte!