# Conectar Sql Server 2014 ao Django 2.2

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, sql-server, django, sql-server-2014

Estou tentando conectar o banco Sql Server ao Django porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro(O conector que estou usado é o django-pyodbc-azure):

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

A configuração do setings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1\test',
    'PORT': '1433',
},}
```

Dependências:

```
Django==2.2.4
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
```

Alguém poderia ajudar com isso?

Comment: Isso responde sua pergunta? [Conectar banco de dados SQL Server no Django](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379211/conectar-banco-de-dados-sql-server-no-django)

Comment: O erro ocorre justamente ao tentar usar o connector django-pyodbc-azure, que é a configuração sugerida na resposta do link.

Comment: Acho que falta instalar o driver do odbc. Na descrição do pacote no pip tem alguns links https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na compatibilidade entre o Django e o python, quando eu usei o pyodbc com o Python 3.4.4 e o Django == 2.2.4 funcionou, e foi isso que fiz:

> -install Python 3.4.4
>   CMD 
>   pip install virtualenv test
>
> teste virtualenv
>
> . \ Scripts \ ativar
>
> pip install Django ==  2.2.4 pip install django-mssql
>
> pip install https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32
>
> django-admin startproject meuprojeto.

Modificar banco de dados de configurações

```
 DATABASES = {    'default': {
>        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
>        'HOST': 'USER-PC\SQL2019',  # Substitua pelo nome do host em que o servidor MSSQL está sendo executado
>        'NAME': 'test',  # Substitua pelo nome do banco de dados no servidor MSSQL
>        'USER': 'USER',  # Substitua pelo nome de usuário
>        'PASSWORD': '1234',  # Substitua pela senha    }, }
```

Comment: Fiz conforme sua resposta porém recebi o seguinte erro: 

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend**

Comment: faça   `'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc'`,coloque a ENGINE que você pretende utilizar.

Comment: Da uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379211/conectar-banco-de-dados-sql-server-no-django?rq=1 ,já tem uma resposta para esse problema.

Comment: Eu segui essa resposta, antes de perguntar, mas ai recebi o erro que coloquei na pergunta.  Já tentei outros conectores também mas ainda não consegui a conexão.

Comment: Cuidado que Python 3.4  essa altura é muito velho e não é mais suportado, nem com atualizações de segurança